# Accessing vue composable instance in function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

Lets say I have a simple vue composable function which I'd like to reuse many times throughout my app. In this case, it's got one reactive property (products, an array containing a list of products), and one method "addProduct" which pushes a new element to the array.

```
export function useCart(){
    const products = ref([])

    const addProduct() =>{
        products.push({item: "Baseball Cap", quantity: 1})
    }

    return {
        products,
        addProduct
    }
}
```

That works fine. However, I'd like to pass the instance of the cart composable to each line, such that the line can access the parent "cart" via the property "cart".

I would expect the following to work. I believe "this" should reference the object (instance of cart) calling the function:

```
export function useCart(){
    const products = ref([])

    const addProduct() =>{
        //this should be the instance of the cart composable?
        products.push({item: "Baseball Cap", quantity: 1, cart: this})
    }

    return {
        products,
        addProduct
    }
}
```

However, when I test in the component consuming the composable, the value of "this" is undefined:

```
const testCart = useCart
testCart.addProduct()
```

Why is "this" undefined in this context, and how can I access the composable instance inside of the composable method?

Comment: Whaty do you expect `this` to be equal to, and why?

Comment: composition api doesnt use `this`; for what you're trying to do sounds like you need a global store, aka `pinia`. Also, when using `ref`, the resulting state is local to the component calling your composable and all other scopes are hidden away. In any case the proper communication between child and parent is an emitted event (or alternatively the provide/inject api for globals), so accessing any parent value from a lesser context is an anti-pattern since it should be using one-way data binding. @corycorycory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do it right, then it works.

But you have to use `functions()` instead of `lambdas`, since `lambdas` have no context and `this = window`

```
const addProduct = function() {
    //this should be the instance of the cart composable?
    products.value.push({item: "Baseball Cap", quantity: 1, cart: this})
}
```

But I struggle to use the `this` context from the .cart property.

Like `cart.products.value[0].cart.products`. It just does not work.

I would suggest you to rethink the design. I would not do it that way.

Check the playground. Second time it's window.

```js
const { ref } = Vue;

const useCart = function() {
    const products = ref([])
    const addProduct1 = function() {
        //this should be the instance of the cart composable?
        products.value.push({item: "Baseball Cap", quantity: 1, cart: this})
    }
    const addProduct2 = () => {
        //this should be the instance of the cart composable?
        products.value.push({item: "Baseball Cap", quantity: 1, cart: this})
    }
    return {
        products,
        addProduct1,
        addProduct2
    }
}

const cart = useCart();
cart.addProduct1();
console.log(cart.products.value[0].cart)
cart.addProduct2();
console.log(cart.products.value[1].cart)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the arrow functions not having context.

Comment: Although that works for functions, it doesn't appear to work with computed properties